# Adding existing model data to spree products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, spree, product

I have an existing website with model data and hundreds of entries. I want to give the catalog e-commerce functionality, so I decided on Spree.

However, I can't figure out how to connect my models data with products in Spree. Basically, all I need to do is add a price to existing data, as well as checkout functionality. I do not want to have to re-add all previous entries.

Anyone have a resource I could read, or thoughts on implementing this?

Is this still what is used?
https://github.com/joshmcarthur/spree-import-products

I'm using the newest version of Rails, ruby 1.9.3 and Spree 2.0.0.beta

Thank you.

Comment: Is the old website based on Rails as well?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a chance to have a look at this Spree Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/298-getting-started-with-spree)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say anything regarding importing products from an existing model, and there's nothing about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your old catalogue schema will probably not be compatible with Spree's Product and Variant models so you'd probably have to write a simple Rake task to do this job, along these lines:

```
LegacyProduct.all.each do |legacy_product|
  Spree::Product.create(:name => legacy_product.title, // etc.
  // create variants etc.
end
```